# GitHub Actions are unable to connect to EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

GitHub Actions are unable to connect to EKS Cluster.

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://test.ukk.us-east-2.eks.amazonaws.com/version": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 255. Error: failed to create kubernetes rest client for read of resource: Get "https://test.ukk.us-east-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 255
```

I am able to connect to the EKS cluster and run all of these from my local machine and the Cluster is a Public Cluster.

GH Action file

```
name: "Terraform Provisioning"

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'terraform/scripts/test-tech-stack/**'
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'terraform/scripts/test-tech-stack/**'
    branches:
      - main
      
jobs:
  terraform:
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.1.7

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init
        working-directory: terraform/scripts/test-tech-stack

      - name: Terraform Apply
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: aws --version; terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
        working-directory: terraform/scripts/test-tech-stack
```

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Done. This has been added.

Comment: Looks like you missed configuring credentials for TF CLI. See https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform and https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/automation/github-actions.

Answer (score 0):

TO be able to connect and deploy applications to `EKS` cluster you need to login to it first.

Please make sure that user connected with credentials that you are using is present in `aws-auth` `configmap` in `kube-system` namespace.

If yes then you should run `aws eks --region example_region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name` command in your pipeline that will generate `.kube/config` file or use some already generated config file in form of secret eg. `${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}`.

Comment: When I was trying to connect from my local, I was using the AWS Secret Key and Access Key. And the same works in my local as well and in the terraform I was using 
```
resource "null_resource" "eks_kubeconfig" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ${module.eks.cluster_name} --region ${var.region}"
  }
}
```

Comment: And 
```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name]
  }
}
```
This is added in my terraform as well.

Comment: Both of these are already in my terraform scripts.

Comment: Any help here, please?

Comment: Could you generate or copy from your local workstation k8s config file that you are sure it is working and place it in `GitHub Actions` pipeline? This will give us some base for further debug.